# How do I let a Discord bot automatically assign a role (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

So I want my bot to instantly add a role to a person who joins my discord. I also thought I'd add a join message as well because why not.
So I have tried to get it to work but it seems I have missed something. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I tried:

````
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'REDACTED';

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Online!')
});


client.on('roleMemberAdd', roleMember =>{
    let welcomeRole = GuildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'User');

    roleMember.roles.add(welcomeRole);
    roleMember.guild.channels.cache.get('781094913285685274').permissionsLocked(`Welcome <@${guildMember.user.id}>`)
});


bot.login(token);```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`roleMemberAdd` isn't a client event, in fact its not even what you are looking for. [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) fires whenever a new member joins the guild, and why do you have two clients?, you are not logging into the `client` instance so it won't fire anyway, and to send a message to a channel you need to use the [.send()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) method.

```
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'REDACTED';

bot.on('ready', () =>{
console.log('Online!')
});


bot.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember =>{
   let welcomeRole = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'User');
   guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole); 
   guildMember.guild.channels.resolve('781094913285685274').send(`Welcome ,@${guildMember.user.id}>`)
})


bot.login(token);
```